# Json skipping arrays insert only what need

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, insert

I have a problem like you can see in json data i have 3 arrays 2 of them
`"kind": "youtube#video",` and one `"kind": "youtube#playlist"`, php code inserting data from json and works perfect but when in json `"kind": "youtube#playlist",` he don't work currently, i need insert only from #video please help i try fix it all day. how SKIP arrays with playlist? only pick information from #video array skipping anothers and getting information only from "kind": "youtube#video", arrays.

> Error when #playlist in json
>
> Notice: Undefined index: videoId in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 62
>
> 62LINE: $videos[$key] = $items['id']['videoId'];

CODE:

```
$loop = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT channelid FROM users ORDER BY id")
    or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
    {
        $channelid = $row['channelid'];
                    $content = file_get_contents($url); 
        $json = json_decode($content, true);    

        if(!isset($json['items'])) continue; //skip if no items

        $videos = ['videoId'=>'','videoId1'=>'','videoId2'=>'','videoId3'=>'','videoId4'=>''];
        $videossw = ['vidname'=>'','vidname1'=>'','vidname2'=>'','vidname3'=>'','vidname4'=>''];
        $videoss = ['publishedAt'=>'','publishedAt1'=>''];
    
        $i = 0;
        //if(isset($videoList[$i]["id"]["videoId"])) {
        foreach($json['items'] as $items)
        {
            $keyy  = 0==$i ? 'publishedAt' : 'publishedAt'.$i;
            $videoss[$keyy] = $items['snippet']['publishedAt'];
            
            $keyyy  = 0==$i ? 'vidname' : 'vidname'.$i;
            $videossw[$keyyy] = $items['snippet']['title']; 

            $key  = 0==$i ? 'videoId' : 'videoId'.$i;
            $videos[$key] = $items['id']['videoId']; 
            ++$i;
        }
        $qqq = 'INSERT INTO users(channelid, publishedAt, publishedAt1, videoId, videoId1, videoId2, videoId3, videoId4, vidname, vidname1, vidname2, vidname3, vidname4) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelid=?, publishedAt=?, publishedAt1=?, videoId=?, videoId1=?, videoId2=?, videoId3=?, videoId4=?, vidname=?, vidname1=?, vidname2=?, vidname3=?, vidname4=?';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($qqq);
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $channelid, $videoss['publishedAt'], $videoss['publishedAt1'], $videos['videoId'], $videos['videoId1'], $videos['videoId2'], $videos['videoId3'], $videos['videoId4'], $videossw['vidname'], $videossw['vidname1'], $videossw['vidname2'], $videossw['vidname3'], $videossw['vidname4'], $channelid, $videoss['publishedAt'], $videoss['publishedAt1'], $videos['videoId'], $videos['videoId1'], $videos['videoId2'], $videos['videoId3'], $videos['videoId4'], $videossw['vidname'], $videossw['vidname1'], $videossw['vidname2'], $videossw['vidname3'], $videossw['vidname4']);
        
        $stmt->execute();

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a condition just after

```
foreach ($json['items'] as $items) {
```

that disqualifies the data.

```
if ($items['id']['kind'] != 'youtube#playlist') {
```

---

Implementation:

```
foreach ($json['items'] as $i => $items) {
    if ($items['id']['kind'] != 'youtube#playlist') {
        $keyy = !$i ? 'publishedAt' : "publishedAt$i";
        $videoss[$keyy] = $items['snippet']['publishedAt'];

        $keyyy = !$i ? 'vidname' : "vidname$i";
        $videossw[$keyyy] = $items['snippet']['title']; 

        $key = !$i ? 'videoId' : "videoId$i";
        $videos[$key] = $items['id']['videoId']; 
    }
}
```